# How do I initialize a multidimensional array of Objects in TypeScript?

Tags: object, multidimensional-array, typescript

I'm working on a project where I need to procedurally generate a number of tiles which define a game board. My plan is to hold these 'Tile' objects in a multi-dimensional array property of a 'Land' object. This way the row and column of the array correspond to the position of the tile, both in the array and on the game board. In short, I'm attempting to do something like this:

```
class Thing {
   tProp: number = 5;
   tMethod() {this.tProp *= this.tProp;}
}

class Environment {
   thingArray: Thing[][];
}

var testEnv = new Environment;
testEnv.thingArray = [];
testEnv.thingArray[0] = [];
testEnv.thingArray[0][0] = new Thing;
var squaredThing = testEnv.thingArray[0][0].tMethod();
```

The variable 'squaredThing' should equal 25; instead the TypeScript compiler returns an error like this:

```
"error TS2339: Property 'tMethod' does not exist on type 'Thing[]'"
```

Is usage of multidimensional arrays to store objects this way not possible in TypeScript, or am I making an error in code structure/syntax?

EDIT: The syntax listed above is actually correct, I had mistakenly left a debugging line in the code, which referred only to the first dimension of the array, as follows:

```
testEnv.thingArray[0].tMethod();
```

It was this that caused the compiling error.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the code you provided, it works correctly here. Could it be a typo in your actual source? If I write `testEnv.thingArray[0].tMethod();` the error I get is identical to what you described, which is expected.

Comment: What John White said is exactly correct, I had accidentally left a debugging line referring solely to the first dimension of the array, and it was this that was throwing the error while compiling.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You only created one array but you want two, should be:

```
testEnv.thingArray = [];
testEnv.thingArray[0] = []; // you are missing this
testEnv.thingArray[0][0] = new Thing;
```

But the error message you receive is weird, it should complain about not being able to get item 0 from `undefined` when you are doing:

```
testEnv.thingArray[0][0] = new Thing;
```

Comment: I think I can understand why the line you suggested would be necessary. I added in the line, but I'm still receiving the same error.  The text of the error almost sounds like it's expecting 'Thing[]' to be it's own class, which it cannot find.

Answer (score 0):

I only see an error about referencing the tProp as **this.tProp**

Have you tried

```
class Thing {
  tProp: number = 5;
  tMethod() { this.tProp *= this.tProp;}
}
```

Everything else looks valid.

Comment: That was a good catch, I missed that in the simplified example above but referred to it correctly as 'this.row' in my real code, so that shouldn't be the problem.